# Curl redirect not working?

Tags: php, curl

My CURL redirect is not working i am redirected to same page but the same page is empty when it is rendered after i submit it. Here is my code.

```
 $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/soft/entercode.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'variable1=abc&variable2=123');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You should try this [thread.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023894/redirect-using-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into the configurations cause this error is sometime caused by installed CURL check that if the installation files have all the required files for win 32 version of CURL.

Comment: yeah later i found that Curl installation with windows 32 bit had some issues i needed to download 2 library files. Now its working fine tho CURl is already installed as mentioned earlier needed to download 2 library files

Comment: @temp-learn: Could you please post the details of the files which you found missing ?(if you still remember). I am having the same problem and would be helped a lot. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding and changing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: thx for replying not working tried it. I am getting internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/soft/entercode.php");    
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'variable1=abc&variable2=123');    
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Check this it will work ..

Comment: thx for replying but it is not working. i am getting this 500 Internal Server Error - http://(myUrl);"

Comment: that may be because of some bad config of server

Comment: yeah later i found that Curl installation with windows 32 bit had some issues i needed to download 2 library files. Now its working fine tho CURl is already installed as mentioned earlier needed to download 2 library files.